# Print Tree in C

Tags: c, printing, tree

I want to develop a function to visualize a tree in the console. For example I'd like an output like this:

```
       2               
      / \       
     /   \      
    /     \     
   /       \    
   7       5       
  / \       \   
 /   \       \  
 2   6       9   
    / \     /   
    5 8     4
```

I have thought of many ways to do this. However, every solution needs extra pointers to siblings. Since I develop a red-black tree, that means that I have to add much more lines of code on other functions like insert(), delete() and rotations to set sibling pointers every time something changes. So, is there anybody who has already developed such a function in C?

Comment: While completely possible, the problem with this is getting your function to be intelligent about recognizing where to branch so that A) there is enough space for all future branches and B) being able to fit more than 2 childs within a small amount of space. While it sounds simple as a concept, this is actually a full research size program. As such it may be too broad. However, instead of displaying it like you want it to right now, the `tree` terminal command may give an easier representation of a tree.

Comment: You tree certainly has an interesting ordering paradigm!

Comment: make a little go of it ,before waiting others to solve it for you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is not so difficult and does not require any modification to your node structures.  You need to follow these steps:

- determine `h` the height of the tree and `w` the maximum width of the node values.
- the width of the last line is `width = (w+1) * pow(2, h) - 1` characters.
- the number of lines is `height = h + (width-w-2) / 2`.
- allocate a 2D char array for the output.
- using a carefully crafted recursive routine, *draw* the tree into the matrix.  hint: you need to pass `h`, `w`, `width`, `height`, the node ptr, its depth and its horizontal position and vertical positions.
- for each node, compose the node value at the position, and for each non null child left and right, compute its relative the position, draw the link and recurse.
- output the 2D matrix.

Comment: I am sure I have done this or similar, so for "carefully crafted" read "tricky" w.r.t the horizontal alignments.

Comment: The horizontal position of the middle of the node value can be computed incrementally by subtracting (resp adding) a delta for the left (resp right) node.  This delta is then halved upon recursion. The vertical delta is the horizontal delta + 1.

Comment: Note that you can produce better looking output with fewer lines using this pattern `\___` and a single `\` on the next line when the horizontal delta exceeds 2.

Comment: That's an easy solution but it really only works for balanced trees; otherwise, it uses way too much horizontal space.

Comment: @rici: I don't deny that, the OP's example indeed uses too much horizontal space as can bee seen by selecting the area with the mouse.  Some of this waste can be removed by scanning for all white initial and final columns.